# Op Amp rails to negative supply when supply voltage is +-5V. However, supplying +-12V "overcomes" this railing, and the op amp begins to properly work

Tags: operational-amplifier

The op amp rails to the negative supply rail with +-5V power supply. If I turn up the voltage supply to +-12V, the op amp begins to work properly. When I turn the voltage back down to +-5V without turning off power, the circuit continues to work properly. However, if I touch a probe to IN- after I've raised and lowered the voltage again, the op amp goes back to railing near the -5V rail.

Here is the circuit I am using. I am using an LT6236 ([datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/623637fb.pdf) here). Power supply is only "allowed" to be +-5V, not +-12V according to the datasheet. However, I cannot overcome this negative railing without turning up the voltage. The railing was true before I turned up the supply voltage, so that has not damaged it so far. I have also tested on different pcbs, and get the same effect, so i dont believe it is a component failure. Any advice on what I am missing would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is this circuit supposed to do? With the feedback on the non-inverting input it looks like a bit like a Schmitt trigger. Also the resistor values seem a bit low, you might be asking the output to supply more current than it is capable of.

Comment: Where did you buy the part from?

Comment: It would be much easier to analyze your circuit if you drew the opamp using an opamp symbol rather than a nondescript block.

Comment: What are you measuring the output with? An oscilloscope or a multimeter?

Comment: You have some strong positive feedback here, so I would expect it to drive the output close to one of the supplies and stay there--I don't find this behaviour surprising. And the behaviour changing after applying ±12 V isn't surprising either--you've probably killed the part at that point, so who knows what it'll do. That's nearly double the absolute maximum rating.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I drove +-12V on one board to see the behavior. So even if I fried that one, the others are still railing at -5V. The other boards have not been supplied overvoltage. This behavior appears even if I ground the input into the opamp, so it should not be outside the range or clip. I get -5V independent of whatever I feed into the op amp.
Also, this op amp is being used as one stage of a 2stage bandpass filter centered at 30khz with 75v/v gain.

Comment: @ScottMay you still have that strong positive feedback I mentioned. That will make the amplifier either go immediately to one of the rails (which one depends on a combination of noise and the amplifier's input offset voltage) or oscillate. What filter topology are you using? I think you may have made a mistake; i'm not aware of any active filter topology where you use positive DC feedback (though positive AC feedback may be used with care in some cases).

Comment: @Hearth. Since both feedback resistors are quite small, I don't even see how the circuit could reach a stable DC operation point. I also cold not find a similar filter topology.

Comment: @devnull I didn't give it any analysis, just saw the positive feedback and thought that must be the problem. Though you're right, I think it would be oscillating if this was the only problem--though someone else pointed out below that this is not an RRIO op amp, just rail-to-rail output, and that may be the reason it sticks to one rail instead of oscillating.

Comment: @Hearth Yes, I agree. Input offset changes polarity close to the rails, output current sink/source capabilities change drastically.

Comment: @devnull Weirdly, I just threw this together in LTspice and the simulation suggests it ought to be stable, even if I apply a perturbation to it. I normally trust LTspice to be reliable when it comes to LT-branded parts... but I can't see how this would actually work.

Comment: @Hearth Same here. But if I multiply the resistors by 10x it oscillates at 3.8MHz and by 100x it drops to 1.7 MHz, but it reaches the rails. That is a beauty! Well, 0V is a possible ideal equilibrium. ;)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your feedback. I simulated everything in LTSpice first, so I was especially confused why it did not work. I believe the LTSpice simulation is incorrect, and after reviewing the positive feedback comments, I do not believe my used design will work. This design is based on Analog Wizard and I must have messed up my math on confirmation. I did the dumb thing and assumed it would work after an LTSpice simulation. Back to the drawing board. Thanks everyone for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you acquired this device from a reputable source, after applying almost twice the maximum voltage informed at the datasheet, it is not expected that it should continue to work normally:

[image]

> *Stresses beyond those listed under Absolute Maximum Ratings
> may cause permanent damage to the device. Exposure to any Absolute
> Maximum Rating condition for extended periods may affect device
> reliability and lifetime.*

Edit regarding the comments about the strong feedbacks. Even considering an ideal opamp (except for output limitation), there should not be a DC stable point:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I acquired the devices from Digikey, so I am assuming they are reputable. Also, I only drove one board at the +-12V. The other boards have only ever received +-5V, so overvoltage does not explain the behavior

Comment: Thank you! Accepted this as answer. I must have made a mistake in my filter math that I cant find, as my circuit for 100v/v and 20v/v worked correctly. I appreciate the annotated picture, and have confirmed that the voltages shown are quite close to my real-world use.

Comment: You are welcome. Analog devices filter design tools (https://tools.analog.com/en/filterwizard/) include many LT devices and may be useful at this stage.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The opamp does have rail to rail output, but not rail to rail input.

From the resistor values on the schematic, voltage on the positive input will be outside of the allowed range when the output clips. Therefore it operates the input stage out of spec, and it doesn't work.

Solution: use a rail to rail input and output opamp.

Comment: +1 It is even worse on the inverting input, through R32 (DC), since there is a comment about testing with the output disconnected (IN- receives the full output voltage).

Comment: This might make sense, but would I still get the same behavior if I grounded the input to the opamp (labeled "preamplifier in") and still got -5V out?

Comment: Doesn't matter. During power-up, the input stage always receives voltages out of normal range, so the opamp will clip against one rail or both until it settles. But in your schematic, it can't settle, because once the output is against the rail, that feeds back to the input and it stays outside of allowed range.